# How come that some tabs in Chrome have different time zone?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timezone

The initial problem is that my Slack in a Chrome tab shows bad message timestamps - off by one hour. As it looks like a time zone problem, I decided to investigate with:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
```

My normal tabs return `-60`, while eg. Slack (and few others) return `0`.

I was not able to find any documentation relating to how to set a default timezone for a particular tab. What could have possibly gone wrong? (Re-starting the OS, Browser and setting time zone in Slack's profile had no effect.)

Comment: Maybe something to do with Daylight Savings? Just a shot in the dark though, because I don't expect different timezones in different tabs either

Comment: There's no JavaScript API that actually can do that, so the explanation is probably more mundane.  Are you sure the code showing an hour off is actually the same as shown here? `new Date()`, not some other date where DST is applicable?  It's also possible that the `Date` prototype has been patched in some way by the application code, but you'd have to give an example.  You say by Slack and a few others, but can you be more specific? This is one case where a screenshot might help.  If we can't reproduce the problem, then it is quite difficult to solve.

Comment: It's the code verbatim as in the post, pasted to DevTools. Gmail, Slack, WhatsApp are affected (showing times incorrectly), Google Calendar also has the `0` offset, but the red mark showing current time is ok.

Comment: Please supply the output of `navigator.userAgent`, `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`, and `new Date().toString()`, and tell us also if they differ between a blank tab (url: `about:blank`) and any of the others.  Thanks.

Comment: My javascript timezone properties in Chrome 71.0.3578.98 x64 have been wonky since a week ago, ever since I did an in-place upgrade from Win7 to Win10.  Right now I have two tabs open to the same site.  In one I get "Etc/ Unknown" and "Tue Jan 01 2019 02:00:54 GMT+0000 (GMT)".  The other tab gives me undefined and "Mon Dec 31 2018 21:00:50 GMT-0500 (GMT-05:00)"

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior any more since (auto)upgrading to `71.0.3578.98` (x64, Win7).